# ¿Como puedo visualizar la animación de un cursor.ani dentro de un control personalizado en C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animación, cursor

**Hola que tal, les agradecería su ayuda.**

Respecto a mi pregunta quiero que me indiquen o me informen como puedo lograr ese objetivo.

Visualizar el cursor.ani de forma infinita en un control personalizado que reciba el string de la ruta del cursor que mostrara en dicho control personalizado.

un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr es como en configuración de Window en el apartado de puntero en el pequeño cuadro puedo ver la animación.

- **NOTA:** *No es que al pasar el cursor actual que usa el sistema encima del control personalizado muestre el cursor animado, ni solo en el programa. Es que dicho control permita visualizar el cursor animado como lo hace Windows en la imagen mas abajo como ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no hay manera sencilla de hacer lo que tu quieres, deberás crear un código que lea el archivo, y si bien esto no es simple tampoco es en extremo difícil, pero escapa a lo que alguien podría responder aquí. Cual es el sentido de usar `ani` y no otro formato animado como gif??

Comment: @Yussef 

Entiendo, el fin para eso era para visualizarlo animado directo del cursor.ani, y tampoco encontré manera de convertir el ani extrayendo los frames para volverlo gif o webp y asi q se visualice mas fácil en el control personalizado, gracias por la información, pensaba poner un mini programa para visualizar la animación de dichos cursores. ¿Que me recomiendas?

Comment: Si tienes el código que extrae los frames (y la cabecera) deberías colocarlo en tu pregunta,  terminar o corregir ese código puede que tenga un alcance que permita generar una respuesta. Por otro lado quizás existe un convertidor por línea de comando como por ejemplo https://imagemagick.org/ (no sé si soporta ani), entonces el WPF llama a la línea de comandos y te genera un gif en una carpeta temporal y de ahí lo lees.